# second fundamental form and the mean curvature of the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

We consider the map $\varphi_0:\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\varphi_0(\theta_1,\theta_2)=R(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2,\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2,\sin\theta_1)$. I know that the induced riemmannian metic is

[image]

From this, how can I obtain that the second fundamental form is

[image]

and mean curvature H=-2/R?

Comment: But I know that the second fundamental form is $h_{ij}X^iY^i$ where $ h_{ij}=g\bigg(\nu,\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}\bigg)$ . ($\nu$ is the normal vector). Even applying this formula, however, I am unable to obtain what is written above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to compute the normal vector $n$ first, where $n$ is the unit vector along $\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x^1}$ x $\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x^2}$. Then by definition, $h_{ij}$ would be the inner product of $\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}$ and $n$. The mean curvature is just half the trace of the Weingarten Map matrix, which can be obtained by multiplying the matrix of the second fundamental from and the inverse of the metric matrix.